# dispatch: debounce expects a function

Tags: redux, lodash, debouncing

I'm trying to debounce a dispatch.
Here is code i wrote:

```
_.debounce(dispatch(_save(arr)),200)
```

But it doesn't work. The console says that `debounce` expects a function, isn't a `dispatch` a function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it says it expects a function means it expect a function reference not a function call which will return a value.

So in your example it should be like `A(B)` not `A(B())`

```
funtion A(){
// some stuff
}
funtion B(){
//some other stuff
}
```

or maybe in another scenario it will be something like this:

```
function A(){
// some stuff
} 
function B(){
// some stuff
  return C;
} 
function C(){
// some stuff
}
```

So now `A(B())` would be valid cause `B()` returns function

Comment: Thanks,i found out how to resolve it  one minute ago. I was trying it too but returning a dispatch wasn't right, i had to save the dispatch in a variable and return it.

Comment: @erikabianchi so did my answer helped you? so you may wanna accept in or upvote it?